# Object key name with dash

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have to make an object with `-` like:

```
let myObject = {
  one-property: 'assignee'
}
```

but JavaScript does not allow this. So any trick to make this work with `-`? My whole backend has objects with `-` on keys.

Comment: let myObject = {
  'one-property': 'assignee'
}

Javascript Object Keys using Special Characters must be wrapped in speech marks.

Comment: ^ the above is true, and you can access it with `myObject["one-property"]`

Comment: @erik.hac yes it does https://jsfiddle.net/6zwdc1fs/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to put the key in quotes

```
let myObject = {
  'one-property': 'assignee'
}
```